# Encrypt/decrypt data sent via visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

How do I encrypt data that I am sending to external web-service from visualforce page. I also need to decrypt that data on web-service's end. Is there built-in feature for something like this?

Comment: Apart from Martin answers http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/06/using-rsa-sha1-with-salesforce-crypto-class/                                        In case you may need URL encode and base 64 encode and decode use http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using https to talk to your endpoint ought to be good enough for most use cases?

If you want to encrypt something manually, take a look at the Crypto-class:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class